# What do I do after I json_encode() my php array?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am new to both php and javascript and having trouble understanding how to communicate between the two. I have a php array and I used json_encode() to turn it into json and now I just don't know what to do from there. I have just been looking around and haven't been able to find an answer of what to do from there. Do I print it? If I do print it... how do I used javascript to grab it. I can't use the php variable name since javascript doesn't understand it. I am just not grasping this concept.

Comment: You'll need an HTTP (Web) server like Apache that will need to be set up to serve content from your PHP script. You can start here: https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most popular way to make a Javascript script communicate with a PHP script is via **Asynchronous Javascript And XML (AJAX) requests**.

In AJAX requests, your javascript code calls the PHP script needed, sending to it any required parameters. Then, your PHP script should print (echo) the result (the JSON encoded array in your case), and when it does, an event gets fired in your javascript code, which you can handle accordingly.

In Javascript, there are two main ways of performing AJAX requests:

**1- Using the `XMLHTTPRequest` object:**

In this method, we are using a Javascript XMLHTTPRequest object to send the request to our PHP script, and we handle its `onload` event to get the response and do something with it :

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "some_url.php?param1=123");
xmlhttp.send();
xmlhttp.onload = function() {
    //here the response from the PHP script is saved in the this.responseText variable

    //parsing the JSON string we got into an actual array
    var myArray = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    //do something with the array
}
```

(note that we can also handle the object's `onreadystatechange`, but `onload` is a bit simpler to handle)

**2- Using a promise (`fetch`):**

```
fetch("some_url.php?param1=123")
.then(function(response) {
    return response.text();
})
.then(function(data)) {
    var myArray = JSON.parse(data);
    //do something with the array
});
```

Comment: Don't use `response.text` when you expect JSON, use [`response.json`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json).